Desplegar campos cuando se seleccione otro campo
Quiero que cuando se seleccione "pagar" se desplieguen más campos como datos de tarjeta, etc.

Éste es el código que tengo hasta el momento:
    JRadioButton rdbtnPago = new JRadioButton("Pagar");
    rdbtnPago.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12));
    rdbtnPago.setBounds(10, 387, 109, 23);
    contentPane.add(rdbtnPago);


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! No se entiende cual es el problema...

Esto lo puedes realizar mediante un ActionListener, el cual configurarias a tu JRadioButton, en este caso al seleccionar, cambiarías a visible tu campo datos de tarjeta, cuando no este seleccionado escondes tu campo de datos de tarjeta, este es un ejemplo:
rdbtnPago.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (rdbtnPago.isSelected()) {
                    //* Si se selecciona, muestra campo datos de tarjeta                    
                    txtDatosTarjeta.setVisible(true);
                } else {
                    //* Oculta campo datos de tarjeta
                    txtDatosTarjeta.setVisible(false);
                }
            }
        });

